# Is udev also a pseudo-filesystem type?

Tags: filesystems, udev

On an embedded device running GNU/Linux with a custom BSP, when I type

```
df /dev
```

in Filesystem column I get

```
devtmpfs
```

```
ps -A | grep udev
```

gives

```
224 ?      00:00:00 systemd-udevd
```

In a PC running Ubuntu 22.04, the same commands give

```
udev
```

and

```
744 ?      00:00:02 systemd-udevd
```

respectively.

My understanding is that the embedded device is using a combination of devtmpfs creating device nodes + systemd-udevd managing ownership and permissions on top of it. Therefore devtmpfs as the filesystem type of /dev.
On the other hand, Ubuntu is running udev with a dedicated udev pseudo-filesystem type.

1. Is this correct?
2. Is udev (besides being the whole solution with a daemon running in userspace) also a specific pseudofilesystem type?
3. I thought that "classic" udev configuration used a generic tmpfs for /dev. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No (see below).
2. `df` shows the mount device; pseudo-file systems don’t have one, and their name is arbitrary. If you run `mount` you’ll see the actual file system type, which is `devtmpfs` on Ubuntu as well.
3. `udev` used to use a generic `tmpfs`, but since `devtmpfs`’s creation in 2009, `/dev` uses the latter.